# Is it possible to make AWS Websocket + Lambda function to constant monitoring of the DynamoDB and send response to the client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a serverless project: AWS + Angular on the frontend. Currently, I get the data when page is initialized and refresh the data when press "update" button. However, I want to monitor changes in the table constantly. In Firebase there is `onSnapShot()` method, which sends the new data when a collection is updated.

I want to make something similar with AWS. However, in [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-wscat.html), I do not see how to correctly do it.

So here are 2 questions:

- How can I connect to the WebSocket with aws-sdk? (Currently, I can connect only from the terminal with `wscat -c myurl` call. Or shall I simply send http.Post with websocket url?
- is it possible to pass invoke in the callback URL? - I want to get data from DynamoDB when page initialize and then invoke it again and again (with a callback URL)

My Lambda function looks like this:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    let params = {
        TableName: "documents"
    }

    let respond = await db.scan(params).promise();
    return  respond;
};
```

On the front-end I have:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
      accessKeyId: '//mykey', secretAccessKey: '//mysecretkey'
    })
    AWS.config.update({
      region:'//myregion'
    })

    this.updateTable() // triggers post request to APi Gateway => lambda and receives a response with data.

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you will need to set up a DynamoDB stream and a lambda function that respond to the database CRUD events, send the updated data to the WebSocket connection if the event data matches the criteria (document id for example), through `AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi`. (FYI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ApiGatewayManagementApi.html)

Comment: Ok, I kind of understand your logic, but then again. How to invoke the initial reading? We have to split those functions then?

Comment: I think so, you probably need to split the logic into two functions.

Comment: Hi Rex, do you know how to correctly make the trigger works on Lambda? Currently it detects the changes, launches the lambda and lambda scan the database, which has not yet been changed.

Comment: The lambda function should be triggered only if items in DynamoDB has been inserted,  modified or removed.
You can config the DynamoDB stream to output both new and old items, and received those items and the event name (`INSERT`, `MODIFY`, `REMOVE`) in your lambda function, from the 1st event argument.
`exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => { event.Records.forEach(r => console.log(r.eventName))); }`

Comment: As above, no table scan is needed. FYR: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb-example.html

Comment: Then I'm sorry, but don't get the point. ApiManagement has post to connection event and sends data. But to get data we need trigger lambda function and this one scans the DynamoDB table. 

If I understand correctly with Isert / Modify you talking about DynamoDB streams. I'm trying with that right now, but question was about scan... Probably it's not possible...

Comment: Oh sorry, I get you wrong. If you could define some index or use the primary key, then you can use `query` instead of `scan`, and that would be a lot cheaper. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452219/what-is-the-difference-between-scan-and-query-in-dynamodb-when-use-scan-query

Comment: I guess the point is not in cheaper productivity, but in the speed and asynchronous of actions. Streams allow to work with latest data, but here I faced another problem. I get object of the data with :S or :N symbols required to record correctly of the item into DynamoDB. Issue that i'm not sure how to remove them without making complicate code.