# Is there a way to retrieve all items in a single table using partition key in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am currently trying my hands on AWS DynamoDB, and have created a simple user table with user_id as partition key and other attributes as first_name and last_name.

I want to list all of the users stored.

I am trying to perform a simple CRUD over it, and can retrieve single user, update item and delete item.
Retrieving all users is fairly simple task, but I am not able to make a query to do the same.

I have used scan operation and it works fine, but I want to write a query for the same.
I want to go to the table and get all items with [user_id,first_name,last_name] for my 'list_users' function.

I am new to AWS DynamoDB, regrets if this is a silly question.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like a `Scan` is indeed exactly what you are looking for. What's wrong with it? What does you mean "I want to write a query for the same"? Do you mean a `Query` operation? Why, what's wrong with a `Scan` if it does exactly what you want?

Comment: @NadavHar'El Sure `Scan` works well, was just trying to know other possible ways.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to use a GSI. GSIs are "alternative views" of a table, and they are eventually consistent. GSis also have separate scaling properties, and you can provision different throughput for a GSI than for your main table.

In your case though, there's not really any data in the table to add the GSI to to make it possible to list users. So an alternative option is to use a *single table design*. What this means, is to normalize the data in your table so that the data matches your query patterns. So let's say all you want to do is to get/update a single user, list users, and just to add to the example, add an email attribute and ensure that it's unique.

This is what a single user could look like in your table to achieve that.

| PK | SK | firstName | lastName | email | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_123 | main | Jane | Doe | jane@gmail.com |  |
| user_list | user_123 | Jane | Doe |  |  |
| user_email | user_jane@gmail.com |  |  |  | user_123 |

Note how the listing only includes the firstName and lastName - you only need to add data to your `ùser_list` key that you actually want to return.

With multiple users in the table, it'll look like this:

| PK | SK | firstName | lastName | email | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_123 | main | Jane | Doe | jane@gmail.com |  |
| user_456 | main | John | Doe | john@gmail.com |  |
| user_list | user_123 | Jane | Doe |  |  |
| user_list | user_456 | John | Doe |  |  |
| user_email | user_jane@gmail.com |  |  |  | user_123 |
| user_email | user_john@gmail.com |  |  |  | user_456 |

This is a structure that allows you to query for the PK `user_list` and get all the users. When you write data, use a transaction with a condition expression that ensures the user_email does not already exist for that e-mail, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to understand is this: queries are restricted to a single partition, scans cover the whole table. For a deeper dive on Query vs. Scan, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452219/what-is-the-difference-between-scan-and-query-in-dynamodb-when-use-scan-query).

As [Nadav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8891224/nadav-harel) points out in a comment, since your `user_id` is your partition key, and since you want to "list all of the users stored", then it is impossible to do this with a query operation in general (ignoring the trivial cases where there are 0 or 1 users). If there are 2 or more distinct users, then that implies 2 or more distinct `user_id`s, which means two or more distinct partitions, which means you can't cover all users with a query operation, as that's restricted to a single parition - which in your case is a single user.